# Какой знак препинания тут нужен и нужен ли вообще?

Tags: спп

*Если отчет сдан компания будет внесена в реестр.*

Если бы было "то", я бы поставила запятую...

Answer (score 2):

Нужна запятая, разделяющая части сложноподчинённого предложения с придаточным условным. Придаточное присоединяется к главному подчинительным союзом ЕСЛИ.

***Если отчет сдан, компания будет внесена в реестр.***

Если бы Вы использовали союз ЕСЛИ..., ТО, то запятую тоже поставили бы.

***Если отчет сдан, то компания будет внесена в реестр.***

Comment: Большое спасибо за оперативный ответ!

Comment: @АннаНевермор По правилам сайта благодарность за ответ лучше выражать очками (стрелка вверх) и принятием ответа (галочка рядом с ответом).